# Picking certain number of groups of data in SQL on the fly

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping

[image: Tables of my problem]

I have two tables. On the right is a lookup table and on the left is the table I have a problem with. num is a primary key and WordID is a foreign key that references num. Pri is a number that represents word priority (where lowest numbered word comes first), and ID represents group of words. For my example, I have the following....

Group 1: school cream ball
Group 3: cream ball store
Group 22: door house
Group 5: ball
Group 7: car

Here's the problem.

I want my application to give me the opportunity to add a new word set which can contain new and/or existing words, but only one word at a time.

For example, if I choose the word cream first, two existing groups have that word in it but I'm stuck on how to figure out if those words have extra words and how many extra words.

I'm trying to figure out how to go about this without always having to insert a new record each time if the group of words are the same and in the same order.

I'm trying to make this design as efficient as possible programmatically without wasting disk space.

So basically what I want to do is create a group of words and update the database as I add or eliminate part of the words, so that if the server crashes, at least part of the data is saved.

Any ideas?

---

UPDATE: I added a new example along with code to illustrate my problem better.

```
drop table if exists words;drop table if exists word;drop table if exists name;
create table word(ID Int primary key not null auto_increment, Word varchar(255));
create table name(ID int, Obj int);
create table words(Seq  Int primary key not null auto_increment,NameID Int,WordID Int,foreign key (WordID) references word(ID));

insert into word(Word) values("great"),("pink"),("job"),("ribbon"),("nice"),("red"),("tie"),("bow"); # make up words

# add group 1 = great job (words 1 and 3 respectively).
insert into words(NameID,WordID) values(1,1),(1,3);
# add group 2 = nice job (words 5 and 3 respectively).
insert into words(NameID,WordID) values(2,5),(2,3);
# add group 3 = nice tie (words 5 and 7 respectively).
insert into words(NameID,WordID) values(3,5),(3,7);
# add group 4 = bow tie (words 8 and 7 respectively).
insert into words(NameID,WordID) values(4,8),(4,7);
# add group 5 = nice bow tie (words 5, 8 and 7 respectively).
insert into words(NameID,WordID) values(5,5),(5,8),(5,7);
# add group 6 = nice bow (words 5 and 8 respectively).
insert into words(NameID,WordID) values(6,5),(6,8);

# define three wordsets for object #1 and three for object #2 and two for object #3, and a brand new set for object #4.
insert into name(ID,Obj) values(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(1,2),(4,2),(5,2),(6,3),(5,3),(7,4);

#object 1 has these sets: great job, nice job, nice tie
#object 2 has these sets: great job, bow tie, nice bow tie
#object 3 has these sets: nice bow tie, nice bow
#object 4 has word set 7 which we are about to define.

# At this point, data is ok. Problem starts when new data begins
# So I look for a key (NameID) that hasnt been used yet. in this case, its 7.


# Lets say my application displays each word from the lookup table in its own button on the screen where I can 
# select whatever word I want to add, and on each selection, the button lights up and the database updates.
# if i click the same word again, it is removed and the database is updated.

# so I want to add the word "nice" to set 7 like so...

insert into words(NameID,WordID) values(7,5);

# I can keep that wordset as-is because there is no other instance of that word set. (the set containing only the word "nice"). 
# Lets say I click the "bow" button to add the word "bow" after "nice" to set 7 as well.

insert into words(NameID,WordID) values(7,8);

# now Heres the problem. I have just created the word set nice bow. This also matches word group 6.
# If I keep telling SQL to define objects as the words "nice bow" the way I do it,
# I will have duplicate results, and waste disk space. I will add a few more "nice bow"s to show.

insert into words(NameID,WordID) values(8,5),(8,8);
insert into words(NameID,WordID) values(9,5),(9,8);
insert into words(NameID,WordID) values(10,5),(10,8);

# Running "select * from words" will show the table with the last 5 sets of words being exactly the same. The seq value is only used 
# to determine order. the lower the sequence number, the more closer to the beginning the word is for that group.
```

Somehow I want to convert the last four entries into one to eliminate redundancy on every button click in my application.

[image: Image of my tables showing the problem area that needs to be fixed]

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I understand that I will need to use SELECT, and I think I may need to use COUNT, HAVING, GROUP and all that, but I'm confused

Comment: What you did so far ?

Comment: combinations of group by and having. I am able to get counts of words using `select * from ObjWords group by WordID having count(*)=3;`. Objwords is the 3-column table shown in my question.

Comment: Heres the steps I want to take to build a set of words... 1. Get a random word group ID and random word. (I'll say 10, and 20) 2. Check other groups containing only word 20 alone. If one exists, change group ID to the ID found of the group with word 20 alone. otherwise add a new record.

Comment: My next step is to then use the group id and add another word and remember the last word but before adding another word to the group, see if other groups contain the same two numbers (representing the same two words) and if no such group exists, then add an entry. otherwise, change the group ID to the ID of the group that has the two words.

Comment: And if I want to add a third, and fourth word, etc. same thing happens again. Also, similar things happen if I want to remove words from my list (except that I delete records instead of adding them).

Comment: You should edit the question adding the information passed in your comments, as comments are not persistent (can be deleted)

Comment: I must say you are hiding one table from us. It is a group of words table.

Comment: the group of words is generated via the data in the ID and the WordID columns. for example,  group 3 (as defined by ID) represents all of the words "cream", "ball" and "store".  it has one record for each word.

Answer (score 0):

I am bit unclear about your lengthy question. Still, this is the way you can acheive random selection in MySQL.

```
SELECT A, B, C, D FROM TABLE 
ORDER BY RAND()

OR

SELECT A, B, C, D FROM TABLE,
(SELECT RAND()*A AS A FROM TABLE) AS TMP
WHERE 
TABLE.A = TMP.A
```

Both approches I am suggesting you to try. I have not tried any of them. Try to implement this in your scenario.

Comment: I tried this: `select * from words where wordID in (5,8) group by NameID having count(NameID)=2` to see if I can list all the fields that only have the sets of data circled in red above but it also showed word set number 5. I'm aware word ID's 5 and 8 are in set 5 but it has another word number to it as well which i dont want.